# Finding Differences In Sets

Tags: c#

I have this  class (a partial listing):

```
class CiscoSwitch 
{
  private string _SwitchName = string.Empty;
  public SwitchName {get {return _SwitchName;} set{_SwitchName=value; }}
}
```

I have 2 lists of CiscoSwitch objects. I am trying to compare them to pick out the ones that are not duplicates. I only want the duplicates.  I tried a Lambda expression but got a compiler error that CiscoSwitch was a non-delgate type.

I am now wondering about something like this - it would allow me to use the List.Except() method (I think):

```
static class SwitchComparer
{ 
  static bool CompareSwitchNames(CiscoSwitch s1, CiscoSwitch s2)
         {
            if (sw1.SwitchName == s2.SwitchName) {return true;}
             else {return false;}
         }
}

     // to find the differences 
 // this is a method of the CiscoSwitchClass
private List<CiscoSwitch> FindDifferences(List<CiscoSwitch> List1, List<CiscoSwitch> List2)
{
       return List1.Except(List2, SwitchComparer.CompareSwitchNames();
 }
```

this could also be done with a foreach but I think this way is a lot cleaner, if it is correct.  I am also thinking there are other attributes of a CiscoSwitch I might want to compare some day so could add methods to the SwitchComparer class as I need them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just having a single method like that won't help you. You need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch>` to pass to `Enumerable.Except` - and even then your code would need to be:

```
return List1.Except(List2, new SwitchComparer()).ToList();
```

Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` within `CiscoSwitch` will do the trick more naturally though - and ideally you should implement `IEquatable<CiscoSwitch>` too.

However, it's worth noting that *mutable* types like this don't play terribly nicely with things like `Dictionary<,>` - if you change an object in a way which affects its hash code after you've inserted it as a key into the dictionary, you won't be able to get at it again. Consider making the type immutable if you can.

A couple of other points to note:

- Any time you write:

  ```
  if (condition)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  you should instead write the *far* simpler:

  ```
  return condition;
  ```

  So your `CompareSwitchNames` method would be:

  static bool CompareSwitchNames(CiscoSwitch s1, CiscoSwitch s2)
  {
      return s1.SwitchName == s2.SwitchName;
  }
- Your parameter names for `FindDifferences` should follow .NET naming conventions (e.g. `list1` and `list2`)
- Using `Except` will only find you the elements in the first list which aren't in the second list; if you need to find the symmetric difference, consider using `HashSet<T>` explicitly.

EDIT: If you wanted to have multiple ways of comparing, you could have something like:

```
public static class SwitchComparers
{
    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch> ByName =
        new ByNameComparer();

    public static readonly IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch> ByCost =
        new ByCostComparer();


    private sealed class ByNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch>
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    private sealed class ByCostComparer : IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch>
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: `Except` would miss all the unique elements in `List2` - as far as I can tell that's not what OP wants

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Yup, was adding an edit which included that at the end :)

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  Is it good practice not to make the class that implements IEqualityComparer static?  My thinking is/was that I could then compare other attributes of a CiscoSwitch object using the same static class by having different methods.  If I understand the MSDN examples and the code posted here, without the static class I would need one class for each attribute I wanted to compare.

Comment: @DavidGreen: A class which implements an interface *can't* be static. You could create several different implementations of `IEqualityComparer<T>` and have static properties which return them, admittedly. (Those different implementations could be private nested classes within a static class, if you want. See my edit for an example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet after I asked that I thought I remembered that about static classes. I tried it in VS and it complained. :)  Looking at your code, a static class doesn't seem to add much if I still need to implement separate classes anyway.

Comment: @DavidGreen: It hides those classes away, and gives you simple ways of referring to the singleton instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom comparer:

```
 public class CiscoSwitchComparer : IEqualityComparer<CiscoSwitch>
 {
   public bool Equals(CiscoSwitch x, CiscoSwitch y)
   {
       return x.SwitchName.Equals(y.SwitchName));
   }

   public int GetHashCode(CiscoSwitch obj)
   {
       return obj.SwitchName.GetHashCode();
   }
 }
```

And then:

```
private List<CiscoSwitch> FindDifferences(List<CiscoSwitch> List1, List<CiscoSwitch> List2)
{
    return List1.Concat(List2)
                .Distinct(new CiscoSwitchComparer())
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: From MSDN: We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer interface

Comment: Mhh got any source for that? I don't see anything wrong with my implementation that would warrant a downvote

Answer (score -1):

You should implement [IEqualityComparer[T]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) interface.

> This interface allows the implementation of customized equality
>   comparison for collections. That is, you can create your own
>   definition of equality for type T, and specify that this definition be
>   used with a collection type that accepts the IEqualityComparer
>   generic interface. In the .NET Framework, constructors of the
>   Dictionary generic collection type accept this
>   interface.
>
> A default implementation of this interface is provided by the Default
>   property of the EqualityComparer generic class. The StringComparer
>   class implements IEqualityComparer of type String.
>
> This interface supports only equality comparisons. Customization of
>   comparisons for sorting and ordering is provided by the IComparer
>   generic interface.
>
> We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer class
>   instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer interface, because
>   the EqualityComparer class tests for equality using the
>   IEquatable.Equals method instead of the Object.Equals method. This
>   is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove
>   methods of the Dictionary class and other generic
>   collections.

Comment: Not for Except. We're not trying to do ordering, we're checking for equality.